# loopback destroyAll for couch db not working with query

Tags: couchdb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying out `loopback-connector-couch` database operator for deleting multiple records from **CouchDB** in one shot.
I have records `_id` in an array

Following the API spec for Loopback model as provided in the below api doc

https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-destroyall

```
persist_model.destroyAll({id:{or:["49c199312b7dce75d69124f9e377a682","49c199312b7dce75d69124f9e377a682"]}},function(err,res){
     console.log('records deleted success:'+res);
  });
```

When executing the above code, it does not throw any error but its not deleting any documents

Would appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use `inq` operator if you want to compare the value with multiple value stored in an array as follows:

```
persist_model.destroyAll({ id: { inq: [ "49c199312b7dce75d69124f9e377a682", "49c199312b7dce75d69124f9e377a682" ]}},
    function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('records deleted success:' + res);
    }
);
```

You can read more about `inq` operator [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter).

Comment: Its still not working for me, where clause is not applicable for destroy operation ( its only valid for 'find' operation)....after removing where clause it is still not deleting the records

Comment: ok, mistake from my side. forgot that it only accepts `where` clause. check the updated answer.

Comment: There seems a bug in couch.js connector implementation for destroyAll method. If it finds `id` in the where clause, it calls the `findById` method which ofcourse wont work for multiple values of _id.